# When I Inject any type of DI inside my Consumer, it returns this Error in my Startup (MassTransit)

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

In my project, I use MassTransit to publish and subscribe to Events and also I use RabbitMQ as a message broker.

I have a simple consumer here. Without  DI (`private readonly ILogger<ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer> logger`) Everything works and all consumers catch the event fine, but when I Inject any type of DI inside my Consumer, It returns this Error in my Startup.CS (In Compile-time):

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0310  'ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer' must be a non-abstract
> type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as
> parameter 'TConsumer' in the generic type or method
> 'ConsumerExtensions.Consumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator,
> Action<IConsumerConfigurator>)'    Consultant.API  ...\Infrastructure\DependencyInjection.cs   96  Active

This is my Consumer

```
 public class ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer : IConsumer<ConsultantFinishedEvent>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer> logger;
        public ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer(ILogger<ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ConsultantFinishedEvent> context)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Ans here is my startUp config:**

```
#region ServiceBus adding
    public static IServiceCollection AddEventBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
            {
                config.Host("RabbitURL", h =>
                {
                    h.Username("Username");
                    h.Password("Pass");
                });
                //Register Consumers
                config.ReceiveEndpoint("ConsultantQueue", ep =>
                {
                    ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
                    //vvvvvvvvvvvv Here I got compile time Err  
                    ep.Consumer<ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer>();;
                });
            }));
            //Register RequestClients
            RegisterClients(x);

        });
        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

        return services;
    }

 
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question was posted just before [your follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69168099/each-time-i-publish-message-just-one-of-the-consumers-fired-randomly), I'm going to use the code from that question to explain what is wrong with the code above.

The proper configuration should use the `ConfigureConsumer` method as shown below.

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddEventBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        RegisterMessageConsumers(x);
        RegisterRequestClients(x);

        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host(configuration["EventBusConnection"], h =>
            {
                h.Username(configuration["EventBusUserName"]);
                h.Password(configuration["EventBusPassword"]);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("ConsultantQueue", ep =>
            {
                ep.PrefetchCount = 16;

                ep.ConfigureConsumer<ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer>(context);
            });
            
            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });
}
```