# Each time I Publish message, just one of the consumers fired randomly

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit

I use MassTransit and RabbitMQ in the sample project. I simply try to publish a message and then consume it by 2 separated Consumers. but each time just one of the consumers fired randomly! What is the problem?

this is the sender method

```
 await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new ConsultantFinishedEvent(50));
```

this config in application startup in Publisher:

```
#region Service Bus Config
    public static IServiceCollection AddEventBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            RegisterMessageConsumers(x);
            RegisterRequestClients(x);
            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                cfg.Host(configuration["EventBusConnection"], h =>
                {
                    h.Username(configuration["EventBusUserName"]);
                    h.Password(configuration["EventBusPassword"]);
                });
            });
        });
        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

        return services;
    }

    private static void RegisterMessageConsumers(IServiceCollectionBusConfigurator service)
    {
        //service.AddConsumer<OurConsumerClass>();
    }


    #endregion
```

This is simple consumers:

```
public class ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer : IConsumer<ConsultantFinishedEvent>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ConsultantFinishedEvent> context)
    {
        int xx = 0;
        return null;
    }
}
```

and also this config that I use for all Consumers startups :

```
  #region Service Bus 
    public static IServiceCollection AddEventBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            RegisterMessageConsumers(x);
            RegisterRequestClients(x);
            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                cfg.Host(configuration["EventBusConnection"], h =>
                {
                    h.Username(configuration["EventBusUserName"]);
                    h.Password(configuration["EventBusPassword"]);
                });
                //Register Consumers
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("PatintQueue", ep =>
                {
                    ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
                });
            });
        });
        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
        return services;
    }

    private static void RegisterMessageConsumers(IServiceCollectionBusConfigurator service)
    {
        service.AddConsumer<ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your publisher configuration order needs a little adjustment:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddEventBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        RegisterMessageConsumers(x);
        RegisterRequestClients(x);

        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host(configuration["EventBusConnection"], h =>
            {
                h.Username(configuration["EventBusUserName"]);
                h.Password(configuration["EventBusPassword"]);
            });
            
            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });
}
```

> Notice that `ConfigureEndpoints` should be at the end of the configuration closure

Additionally, you should *not* return `null` as a `Task` in an async method.

```cs
public class ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer : IConsumer<ConsultantFinishedEvent>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ConsultantFinishedEvent> context)
    {
        int xx = 0;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Finally, your configuration on your consumer side needs adjustment as well.

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddEventBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        RegisterMessageConsumers(x);
        RegisterRequestClients(x);

        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host(configuration["EventBusConnection"], h =>
            {
                h.Username(configuration["EventBusUserName"]);
                h.Password(configuration["EventBusPassword"]);
            });

            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });
}
```

MassTransit will load balance across consumer instances by default. If you want to use the same consumer across multiple instances, you can do so by giving the consumer a unique instanceId. Alternatively, you could simply specify that a unique endpoint should be used to consume the event only when the bus instance is running.

To configure a unique persistent instanceId:

```cs
private static void RegisterMessageConsumers(IServiceCollectionBusConfigurator service)
{
    service.AddConsumer<ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer>()
        .Endpoint(e =>
        {
            e.Name = "PatientQueue";
            e.InstanceId = "some-unique-value";
            e.PrefetchCount = 16;
        });
}
```

To configure the consumer as temporary, so it's automatically removed when the instance exits:

```cs
private static void RegisterMessageConsumers(IServiceCollectionBusConfigurator service)
{
    service.AddConsumer<ConsultantFinishedEventConsumer>()
        .Endpoint(e =>
        {
            e.Name = "PatientQueue";
            e.InstanceId = "some-unique-value";
            e.PrefetchCount = 16;

            e.Temporary = true;
        });
}
```